# How to write this rewrite rule in Apache?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

If user visits `/abc`,

and there is no file/directory named `abc` under `/`,redirect it to `/test.php?from=abc`,

but if it exists,don't redirect.

Comment: Keep in mind that someone who knows the answer may not be posting because you have only accepted answers on half of your 155 questions.

Comment: This really belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php?from=$1
```

`RewriteCond` is a conditional - the following rule will only execute if the condition is true.

The `-f` test checks if a file exists, the `-d` test checks if a directory exists.

`SCRIPT_FILENAME` will be set to the system path that Apache would use to fetch a file (e.g. `/var/www/html/blah.html`)

So it checks to see that the file doesn't exist, then it checks to see that the directory doesn't exist. If both those conditions are met, it processes the rule.

Example:

- Your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is set to `/var/www/html`
- Your user requests `http://yoursite/blah.html`
- Firstly we check to see if `/var/www/html/blah.html` is a file
- Then we check to see if `/var/www/html/blah.html` is a directory
- If there is no file or directory of that name, it rewrites to `http://yoursite/test.php?from=blah.html`

Documentation for [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: Does it only affect the `RewriteRule` right behind or all `RewriteRule`s?

Comment: It affects only the following rule.

Answer (score 1):

May be like this, tested on xampp in windows.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test.php?from=$1
```